# shutdown.jar work but shutdwon.exe not work

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar, shutdown, exe4j

I just created a GUI program for shutdown PC.
It works fine, so I make a jar file of it which also works.
Now I created an `.exe` file of it by using `exe4j` and `lauch4j`. It will start but when I click on shutdown button nothing happens, `.exe` program does not work.
It irritates me, because no error message comes.

Here is a code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
String str=e.getActionCommand();
    if(e.getSource()==b1) {
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Capture the output from `proc.getErrorStream()` see what it says. It may reveal the error.

Comment: Does your program closes when you click a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path to `shutdown.exe` that you start from your Java application:

```
runtime.exec(System.getenv("SystemRoot") + "\\System32\\"
             + "shutdown -s -t 0");
```

If your Java app is `shutdown.exe`, then `runtime.exec` really starts your Java application instead of the system utility.